# How can I exit graph editor

Tags: 3d-view

[image]I'm working on creating a looping rotation and the tutorial I was following had me use the graph editor at one point. I was really confused by the way that new windows are opened so in my attempts to close it i ended up creating several more. I also elected to hide the header because I thought they might be closed as a result. Long story short, I accidently closed the window I was working on and am left with a graph editor window with no heder and no way to switch back to 3d viewport mode. I can still view my models through the other windows like sculpt and model but I can't work on the animation. Is there anything I can do???

Comment: Can you attach a screendump of Your fullscreen?

Comment: @sorenfroststaal I attached a screenshot. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

To make the header appear again, click the downward facing arrow on top the window :

[image]

Then, you can change the window type as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!